# Que erro é esse que aparece no console, rodando angular?

Tags: angularjs

Estou criando uma aplicação web com angular e não consigo fazer a tela de login aparece na index.html, fora que uma mensagem de erro aparece no console.

> Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.6.2/$injector/modulerr?p0=weset&p1=Error%3A%2…oogleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.6.2%2Fangular.min.js%3A45%3A20)

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app='weset'>
<head>
<title>WESET</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.2/angular.min.js"></script>

<script src="js/app.js"></script>
<script src="js/wesetConfig.js"></script>

<script src="controllers/loginCtrl.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

</head>
<body>

    <div ng-view></div>

    <script src="js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

app.js

```
var app = angular.module('weset', []);
```

controller.js

```
app.controller('loginCtrl', ['$scope', '$http',function($scope, $http){

}])
```

config.js

```
app.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

$stateProvider

.state('login', {
  url: '/login',
  templateUrl: 'templates/login.html',
  controller: 'loginCtrl'
});

$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/login');
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você está tentando utilizar `$urlRouterProvider` sem a menção à inicialização do serviço. Mude a linha

```
var app = angular.module('weset', []);
```

para

```
var app = angular.module('weset', ['ui.router']); // Adiciona ui-router ao 
                                                  // ciclo de inicalização
```

Answer (score 2):

Como o @OnoSendai falou, você está tentando utilizar um serviço sem injetar ele no seu módulo principal da sua aplicação AngularJS.

Sempre que você quiser utilizar um serviço que não seja "nativo" do AngularJS, você precisa importar o arquivo no seu `index.html`, depois ir no seu `angular.module` e adicionar esse módulo, no seu caso você deve adicionar o `ui.router`.

Quando você o adiciona no seu angular module, ele vai criar a referência para o serviço que você está tentando chamar, que é o `$urlRouterProvider`